# Search for a column by name in awk

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a file that has many columns. Let us say "Employee_number" "Employee_name" "Salary". I want to display all entries in a column by giving all or part of the column name. For example if my input "name" I want all the employee names printed. Is it possible to do this in a simple manner using awk?
Thanks

Comment: If someone said "column name matching 'employee'", do you want one or two columns output?

Answer (score 4):

Given a script `getcol.awk` as follows:

```
BEGIN {
    colname = ARGV[1]
    ARGV[1] = ""
    getline
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i ~ colname) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i > NF) exit
}

{print $i}
```

... and the input file `test.txt`:

```
apple   banana  candy   deer    elephant
A   B   C   D   E
A   B   C   D   E
A   B   C   D   E
A   B   C   D   E
A   B   C   D   E
A   B   C   D   E
A   B   C   D   E
```

... the command:

```
$ awk -f getcol.awk b <test.txt
```

... gives the following output:

```
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
```

Note that the output text does not include the first line of the test file, which is treated as a header.

Comment: If there is more than one match then should more than one column be printed?

Comment: @sudo_O: The `if (i > NF) exit` line is executed if there is no match between the argument value and any of the header lines. It results in the body of the program not being executed. Otherwise the program prints as many blank lines as there are lines in the file (excepting the header).

Comment: @Scrutinizer: The OP asked that only the column matching the header in the argument be printed. This program prints the first column whose header matches the argument but not two or more. A modification to print multiple columns for multiple matches would be straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

Simple one-liner will do the trick:

```
$ cat file
a b c 
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3

$ awk -v c="a" 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)n=$i~c?i:n;next}n{print $n}' file
1
1
1

$ awk -v c="b" 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)n=$i~c?i:n;next}n{print $n}' file
2
2
2

$ awk -v c="c" 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)n=$i~c?i:n;next}n{print $n}' file
3
3
3  

# no column d so no output
$ awk -v c="d" 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)n=$i~c?i:n;next}n{print $n}' file
```

Note: as in your requirement you want `name` to match `employee_name` just be aware if you give `employee` you will get the last column matching `employee` this is easily changed however.

Comment: Hi @sudo_O, that should be `print $n`, no?

Comment: Thanks @Scrutinizer I should have used a better input file so this wouldn't have slipped thought.